# how to get value from SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android

I have been making application which uses Preferences. I have following PreferenceActivity:

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefences);

        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.prefences, true);
    }
}
```

also I have following preferences.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <EditTextPreference android:key="device_id" android:title="Device ID"/>
    <ListPreference android:key="update_time" android:entries="@array/update_keys" android:entryValues="@array/update_values" android:title="Update time" android:defaultValue="28800000"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

and I try to get values from SharedPreferences in onCreate() method my main Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    initializeOtherElements();

    SharedPreferences prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    Log.e("key", String.valueOf(prefs.getString("device_id", "1")));
}
```

I have added PreferencesActivity into manifest. But I see "1" in Log always. Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: Have you stored anything in that device_id pref? Otherwise it will return your default value of 1.

Comment: No, i have tried to change key for this settings, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You always see 1 in the log because you have mentioned "1" as the default value to return if "device_id" preference haven't been set. If you set the "device_id" preference to say ABC, ABC will be returned. If you haven't set "device_id" "1" will be returned.

Comment: I know it. But I have set default value and it must work. How can I fix it?

Comment: are you calling commit() after you put the string in preferences?

Comment: No, i don't edit Preferences Programatically. I use PreferenceActivity for it - preferences is saved automatically.